# Midje fails on Macros in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, macros, lisp, midje

Here is the **passing version** of the code:

**Normal function:** That passes

```
(defn my-fn
  []
  (throw (IllegalStateException.)))

(fact
  (my-fn) => (throws IllegalStateException))
```

**Here is the macro version of it:**

```
(defmacro my-fn
  []
  (throw (IllegalStateException.)))

(fact
  (my-fn) => (throws IllegalStateException))
```

Which **fails** here is the output:

```
LOAD FAILURE for example.dsl.is-test
java.lang.IllegalStateException, compiling:(example/dsl/is_test.clj:14:3)
The exception has been stored in #'*me, so `(pst *me)` will show the stack trace.
FAILURE: 1 check failed.  (But 12 succeeded.)
```

It is the same code I just changed **defn** to **defmacro**.

I did not understand that why this is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the thing is your macro is wrong. While your function was throwing an error in runtime, the macro throws it in compile-time. The following should fix that behavior:

```
(defmacro my-fn
  []
  `(throw (IllegalStateException.)))
```

now your macro call would be substituted with the exception being thrown. Something like that:

```
(fact
  (throw (IllegalStateException.)) => (throws IllegalStateException))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!